# How to change the height of table programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have one `UITableView`.

While I run app it shows more height than needed. It's about 3 times the height.

When the cell contents are displayed its showing in between lines but after is its scrolling down with white blank area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Adjust the table cell height in the above method. I am assuming you have the information of what should be the height at what point in your app.